# How do I create a variable in a function that other functions can access in python?

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7, function

How do I make it so that one function can access another variable like this?

```
>>> def foo():
...    pop = 1
...    print pop
...
>>> def oof():
...    pop-=1
...    print pop
...
>>> foo()
1
>>> oof()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in oof
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pop' referenced before assignment
```

This seems to raise an `UnboundLocalError` even though I have assigned `pop` to `1`. Why is this?

Comment: That's a very, very bad approach to programming. If you want functions that keep a shared state, you probably want to build it into an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `global` to make your variables global:

```
>>> def foo():
...     global pop
...     pop = 1
...     print pop
...
>>> def oof():
...     global pop
...     pop-=1
...     print pop
...
>>> foo()
1
>>> oof()
0
>>> oof()
-1
>>>
```

Or you can take in input and return output such as the following:

```
>>> def foo():
...    pop = 1
...    return pop
...
>>> pop = foo()
>>> def oof(pop):
...    pop -=1
...    return pop
...
>>> print pop
1
>>> pop = oof(pop)
    >>> print pop
    0
```

Comment: Another alternative is to encapsulate the state into an object.

Comment: Globals are generally highly discouraged.

Comment: why are they discouraged?

Comment: it's worth noting that `oof` still doesn't modify the global `pop`

Comment: For large programs they become unwieldy, and it's harder to see the flow of the program.

Comment: Yes, that is true. However, I can change that with a `return`.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a case for a [class](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

```
class Bar:
    pop=0
    def foo(self):
        self.pop=1
        print(self.pop)
    def oof(self):
        self.pop-=1
        print(self.pop)

bar=Bar()
bar.foo()
bar.oof()
```